# get all files in drive via REST API

Tags: python, onedrive

I'm trying to access all my files in my drive via the endpoint

```
/me/drive/root/children
```

However it returns 0 children even though the following observations happen:

1. Calling `/me/drive/root` returns:

   ","folder":{"childCount":3},"root":{},"size":28413,"specialFolder":{"name":"documents"}}
2. More interestingly, doing the API call from the Graph Explorer:
   https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/graph-explorer **does** show the 3 files that I have when using `me/drive/root/children`.
3. The graph explorer matches perfectly the API call when using `/me/drive/root`, but not `/me/drive/root/children`.

What is happening?

EDIT:

Following Brad suggestion I decoded the token with  https://jwt.io/ and the parameters scp reads:

```
scp": "Mail.Send User.Read",
```

Second edit:

I removed all the app permissions from apps.dev.microsoft.com and I still have the same observations. It's looks like the permissions I set there have no effect.

Comment: Can you crack open your auth token using something like https://jwt.io/ and let us know what the `scp` value is? It feels permission related.

Comment: "scp": "Mail.Send User.Read",

Comment: You'll need `Files.Read` in order to get access to any of the files - can you add that, get a new token, confirm it's in the `scp` list, and then try the call again?

Comment: I tried that a 1000 times but the permissions don't seem to change :| I removed ALL permissions and still see no change. Not sure what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above follows the example found at:

https://dev.office.com/code-samples-detail/5989

As it turns out, the whole confusing was coming from here:

```
microsoft = oauth.remote_app(
    'microsoft',
    consumer_key=client_id,
        consumer_secret=client_secret,
        request_token_params={'scope': 'User.Read Mail.Send Files.Read Files.ReadWrite'},
        base_url='https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/',
        request_token_url=None,
        access_token_method='POST',
        access_token_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token',
        authorize_url='https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize'
)
```

I did not have the right scopes declared in `request_token_params`. So even if the app has the permissions, without the scopes declared there you cannot access the sheets.